# Topology of countably many seminorms on $C^{k}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Question:

For the space $C^{k}(U)$ of $k$ times differentiable functions on $U$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and with topology induced by the family $||f||_{\alpha,K}=\sup\limits_{x \in K}\big|D^{\alpha}f(x)|$ of seminorms, $K \subset U$ compact and $|\alpha|\leq k$, how can I show I show that there is a countable family of such seminorms that gives the same topology on $C^{k}$?

Background:

Im studying a [document](http://math.rice.edu/~semmes/fun5.pdf) by Stephen Semmes, and having introduced the sup-seminorm topology on $C^{k}$, he'd like to show that there is a countable family of such seminorms that gives the same topology as that induced by the family 
$||f||_{\alpha,K}=\sup\limits_{x \in K}\big|D^{\alpha}f(x)|$ of seminorms.

He starts (page 4, "countably many seminorms") with $\mathbb{R}^n$, equip it with the euclidian norm and reminds the reader that any compact set can be contained in the closed ball $\overline{B}(0,r)$ for some $r > 0$. In particular, he stresses the fact that the closed balls $\overline{B}(x,r)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, are contained in some closed ball centred at $0$. He then says the following:

"This implies that one can get the same topology on $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ using the sequence of supremum seminorms associated to the closed balls $\overline{B}(0,r)$ with $r \in \mathbb{Z}_+$"

He then continues the argument for $C^{k}$ which is what I'm after.

I cannot see the implication, and I don't know where I should to turn to fill my gap. I'd be very thankful for an explanation and how the latter is implied by the former.

Comment: A subset $P$ of your given family of seminorms $Q=\{\|\cdot\|_{\alpha,K}:$ $K$ compact and $|\alpha|\le k\}$ generates the same topology if, for all $q\in Q$, there is $p\in P$ with $q\le p$ (because then every $B_q(x,r)=\{y: q(x-y)<r\}$ contains $B_p(x,r)$).

Comment: So what you're essentially telling me is that the topology $T_P$ on $C^{k}$ induced by the countable family of seminorms $P$, being a subset of the family of seminorms $Q$ , is coarser than the topology $T_Q$ (i.e. $T_P \subset T_Q$) induced by the family $Q$ (for the obvious reason that $P \subset Q$)...

Comment: And conversely, that $T_Q$ is coarser than $T_P$ (i.e. $T_Q \subset T_P$) since for any set $S \in T_Q$ and for any $x \in S$, I may find a basic set $C_q$ of $T_Q$ (a finite intersections of $B_q$ like balls), and a basic set $C_p$ of $T_P$ (a finite intersection of $B_p$ like balls), for which $x \in C_p \subset C_q \subset  S$ ?

Comment: So, your problem is solved. Right?

Comment: Correct Jochen, and thanks for pushing me in the right direction.